# A medium similar to Javascript canvas

Tags: java, c++, c#

I have enjoyed making project in javascript canvas for a while, making fun small games and interactive pages, but as soon as I try to do anything more complex in the canvas, everything begins to slow down very fast.

Although partially a problem with some of the methods I use in my code, but still it doesn't seem like it should be as slow as it is. I then decided to see if javascript is considered to be slower than most other languages and is just not suited for projects such as games, after all, I never saw them used for main game logic before(excluding ui in games like battlefield 1).

I quickly found out that it is on the slower side, and that languages like c#, c++, and java are faster after all.

Assuming that learning these languages is not a problem, is there an equivalent of canvas I could use to make games in these langauges? So far I have been able to find processing for java, but was also curious to find out other options.

Should I just forgo the whole thing and just use some engine like unity instead?

Excited to see your recommendations,
Victor Kim